# Is it possible to save and restore ANTLR4 state to avoid warm-up time?

Tags: antlr4

Using ANTLR v4, the parsing of the first file takes few seconds and the parsing of the following ones is almost instantaneous.

Is it possible to save the state of ANTLR to avoid the warm-up time?

Is `decisionToDFA` the only data structure that should be serialized?

Comment: I can only speak for ANTL3, but I'd be very surprised if ANTLR4 didn't have a similar mechanism. In ANTLR3 you have the possibility to reset parser and lexer and start over with a new string. But you would not create a new parser instance, but instead reuse it from a previous run.

Comment: Yes ANTLR4 offers this mechanism. But, I am not able to share the state between several executions (different process/JVM).
Typically, I would like to train the parser on the standard library of my language and then put the state of the trained parser inside the code of my compiler. Therefore, if I compile only one file, I do not pay the warm-up time.